# Pass values to IN operator in a Worklight SQL adapter

Tags: javascript, sql, ibm-mobilefirst

I have started to work with SQL adapters in Worklight, but I do not understand how can I pass values to an IN condition when invoking my adapter procedure.

Comment: Edit your question with your adapter XML and implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit your question with your adapter's XML as well as implementation JavaScript...
Also, make sure [to read the SQL adapters training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf).

---

What you need to do is have your function get the values:

```
function myFunction (value1, value2) { ... }
```

And your SQL query will use them, like so (just as an example how to pass variables to any SQL query, doesn't matter if it contains an IN condition or not):

```
SELECT * FROM person where name='$[value1]' or id=$[value2];
```

Note the quotation marks for value1 (for text) and lack of for value2 (for numbers).

Comment: Doing so, I am getting an error, Idan. [ERROR   ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'SqlStatement' failed. [project Sample]
invalid type of element

Comment: I don't know how your project and scenario differs from the one here. Open a new question.

Comment: @IdanAdar, how to pass values in IN operator?