# IBM Worklight - Error while using variable in a SQL Adapter query

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using SQL adapter in worklight where I need to have a variable that I need to use it in the query.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012017/pass-values-to-in-operator-in-a-worklight-sql-adapter) and followed the same. But it`s showing the below error.

Pasted the complete error message on using a variable in the SQL adapter.

```
  [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project Sample]Device/SqlStatementFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project Sample]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "parameters": [
            null
         ],
         "preparedStatement": "UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=$[count] WHERE DeviceNames = 'DellTestLap';"
      }
   ]
}
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)..
Performed query:
UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=$[count] WHERE DeviceNames = 'DellTestLap';
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project Sample]java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Project.js

```
     function UpdateDeviceDetails(){


            var count = 2;
            var invocationData2 = {
            adapter : 'Device', // adapter name
            procedure : 'UpdateDeviceDetails', // procedure name
            parameters : [count] 

        };



        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData2,{
            onSuccess : QuerySuccess,
            onFailure : QueryFailure
        });
}
```

Adapter.js

```
var DeviceDetails  = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=$[count] WHERE DeviceNames = 'DellTestLap';");

function UpdateDeviceDetails(count) {

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement :DeviceDetails,
        parameters : [count]
    });
}
```

Comment: the SQL statement in adapter.js and the error message you've quoted do not match; please clarify... update either the error or the SQL statement. Also the function in Project.js does not close properly, I will assume that is just a copy/paste error on your end?

Comment: That was just a copy/paste error Idan. I have pasted the complete error. Pls check the updated question.

Comment: How many times did you invoke the procedure in that error? it seems to be spitting out several iterations. Please, only once.

Comment: In the error it shows '$[count]' but in your adapter it's $[count] - please, double check both the adapter and error and make sure they are synced. If you made changes to your adapter, make sure to redeploy. Since you're passing numbers, it should be $[count] (also in the error theoretically).

Comment: Really sorry for that. And I have just checked with the  '$[count]' once as I have pasted my complete console page. May be u have seen that error. But actually I am using  $[count] now. But Anyways it`s shpwing error for both.

Comment: Replaced it with the error that I have invoked only once. Hope you will take a look at it. It basically shows some 'Parameter index out of range' error. I don`t have any idea why. I Wish there would be some example project available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.sql.SQLException+Parameter+index+out+of+range+%281+%3E+number+of+parameters%2C+which+is+0%29+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen the $[variable_name] syntax being used... what happens when you replace $[count] with "?". Like: UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=? WHERE DeviceNames = 'DellTestLap';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the $[variable_name] syntax with SQL adapters. I've always used "?"

> "UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=? WHERE DeviceNames =
>   'DellTestLap';"

However, assuming that this syntax does work, how is your code referencing the name "count"? The variable "count" is resolved as the number 2. The SQL statement won't be able to know to reference the name count just by the variable name. It would make more sense if the variable passed to parameters was more like this:

```
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement :DeviceDetails,
        parameters : [{ count: 2 }]
    });
```

That being said, I've never used this syntax before, I just use the "?" syntax.

Comment: I'd go with the "?" suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Tried exactly this. It says   [10:59:24.683] "Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException.
Performed query:
UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=? WHERE DeviceNames = 'DellTestLap';"

Comment: It seems that you have accidentally taken both of my suggestions and combined them :)   (or perhaps I just wasn't clear) If you use the first example with the '?' notation, then do NOT use the { count: 2 } as a parameter for the object. If you use the '?' then you can just pass '2' or 'count' as you were before. The { count: 2 } was just a suggestion for the first kind of notation that you were using that I was suggesting not to use. If you use the '?' notation and pass in a JSON object, the adapter will get confused and give you the error you're seeing now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the syntax of ?

```
var DeviceDetails  = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("UPDATE devices SET DeviceQuantity=? WHERE DeviceNames ='DellTestLap';");
```

this will work surely try it !!!!!!!!!!!!!